# Download dynamically generated content using jquery

Tags: jquery, python

I have an application in turbogears that dynamically generates an excel spreadsheet, meaning it is not saved as a file in the server, I set the content type and other headers, so it works fine, my question is if it is possible to trigger a download using jquery. Here is what it looks like:

```
def get_xl(self, **search):
    response.headers['Content-type'] = "application/ms-excel"
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment;filename=myfile.xls"
    book = Workbook()
    ... code that puts stuff in rows ...
    return book.biff_data()
```

This returns the data so when I go to the url on my browser, it triggers the download, however, I need to post some data,and it would be nice if everything can be handled with jquery. This is what I have so far on jquery side, I know is all wrong though:

```
var fields = $('#search-form').serializeObject();
    if ( !fields.length ) {
        alert("Dude, you must search for something.");
        return false;
    }
$.get('/get_xl',fields.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery for this, try changing the `get_xl` method to accept query string parameters, and then just setting the URL to `/get_xl?params_here` using plain ol' javascript - this will trigger the Save / Run download dialog in the browser.

e.g.

```
var fields = $.param('#search-form');
    if ( !fields.length ) {
        alert("Dude, you must search for something.");
        return false;
    }

window.location.href = '/get_xl?' + fields;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by inserting a form element and appending the data you want to POST or GET into hidden fields and triggering the submit event.

The headers you are sending will launch a download, send the Content-Length too so the download progress displays properly.

Comment: Ok, I just set the length, same thing happened :( I can see the response in firebug, it responds ok, but it wont trigger the download.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this using jQuery rather than just pointing the form to get_xl?

Comment: I have an api that does a big query, the form has 2 buttons, one posts the form and returns the data using ajax, the other button is for downloading the excel file using the same parameters, it could be done without jquery, but it would be nice to be able to use it.

Comment: What you're trying to do can't be done with an AJAX request, returning the file in a jQuery $.post or $.get won't launch a download.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off base here, but what I would try doing is posting the form through ajax using the .ajax() function and receiving the data back from the page you're calling.

```
$.post('your-excel-gen-page.py', $('#search-form').serialize(),
        function(data){
            if(data.success == true){
                              // Update iframe using .load() function
            }else{
              // Fail
            }
        }, "json");
```

I'm not a python pro, but I've done this with PDF generates and php pages in the past.  When you post to the page, it should call the page and start the download of the file.  If that doesn't work, you can try populating an iframe on your page with the return contents from the ajax call.  This can be done with the success:function and .load .  Might be worth a try.